# Changing change time of any linux file

Tags: linux

We have a file in linux  for which we want to change the Change time, we can find the change time using the `stat <space> <filename>` command, below is a sample

```
 stat filename

 Change: 2016-03-15 13:34:10.000000000 +0530
```

Comment: Please always remember to Google before asking. A query for `change date linux file` will get you everything you need.

Comment: no it didnt served my purpose , there are three time variables ...2 can be changed but not the third..    here the Change variable is still the same                                                                                              Access: 2016-03-14 15:56:30.759260743 +0530
Modify: 2016-03-14 15:56:30.759260743 +0530
Change: 2016-03-15 13:56:30.758153207 +0530

Comment: So Google e.g. `linux change change time`, yields this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36021/how-can-i-change-change-date-of-file

Comment: i checked that link , the answer was not accepted.

Comment: Why would that matter?

Comment: Are you refering to modified time.

Answer (score 0):

Use "touch" command to modify "modified date & time".

Answer (score 0):

```
touch file-name-here
```

But remember that if the file doesn't exist, touch will create a new empty file.